# Should I add the computer and/or user in a domain?

Tags: windows-domain

Should I add both the user account and the computer name of a specific user or not in a domain?

Or it is OK to add either of the two, computer or user account? And how can I log in the computer that I added when there is no password created in the adding of computer in a domain?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? setup a new computer?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve

If you want a user to be able to log on with their domain account on to a computer that is part of a domain then you would need to create a user account for them (with the appropriate access.) 

You would need the computer account to be joined (added) to a domain in order for it to be able to act as a member of the domain (and to be able to determine if the login request is local or a domain authentication request.)

Comment: @Sickest: I am adding users and their computer to a domain server and want to understand the role of user and computer in adding them in the domain.

Comment: @Enigman: Ahh. so, the adding user account is for the restriction of the user? and adding their computer is for determining whether the user access on a local or into the domain? do mean of local is their local computer and not log onto the domain? Thanks in advance, I am learning.

Comment: What if I only add a user account and I didn't add the computer account? what will happen?

Comment: Your computer has to have a computer name, if you were to network the computers (if you have more then 1) it would require a Computer name.

Answer (score 3):

If you have [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) and [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) set up, you'll just need to join the domain through the `Computer Name` tab on `System Properties.` When you join your domain, you will be prompted to enter valid credentials, so make sure you have at least one user setup on Active Directory.

If you're able to join the domain successfully, the computer name will automatically be added to the default `Computer` folder on Active Directory. The computer name should also appear in the `Forward Lookup Zone` for your domain in the `DNS Manager`. The Forward Lookup Zone will contain your computer name, the Type (A Record) and an IP address.

> In short, you only need to add a user to your domain. The computer
>   will be added when you join the domain using the user's credentials.

When you add a computer to a domain, the local user accounts do not automatically gain access to shared folders/files on the domain controller or any other computer/device that is part of the domain. To access folders/files on your server machine/domain controller you will have to provide Active Directory credentials. You can choose to "Remember the credentials," which will store them in the `Credential Manager`, which in turn will give you access to the shared folders without having to enter in your details every time.

Once your computer is a member of the domain, you should have the ability to login to your computer using Active Directory credentials. This will create a local account on your computer and any deployment rules that you have setup on your server will be applied to that account. As an example, you can set up `Group Policy Objects` to deploy software. Obviously, that is beyond the scope of your question, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join a computer to a domain then yes, you will need to create a computer object, but the only objection is that you need to be a domain administrator. There are more than enough reasons as to why you would want separate accounts, but after joining the server to a domain you will now need to log in as a domain user. It is true that you can still login using local accounts, but if you try to reach network resources in a domain you will have to provide domain user credentials.

The user can be created in Active Directory. A quick Google search will get you step-by-step screenshots.